# Date validation in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have two date-time picker controls for FROM and TO date. I want to limit the TO date starting date to the FROM date.

Example: If FROM date is 4/12/2013
The TO date picker should allow the user to select date only from 4/12/2013 to current date.

The code is as follows in DoDataExchange() method.

```
 DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_DATETIME_FILTER_FROM, m_daysStartDateVal);
 DDV_MinMaxDateTime(pDX, m_daysStartDateVal,&StartDate,&COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime());
 DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_DATETIME_FILTER_TO, m_daysEndDateVal);
 DDV_MinMaxDateTime(pDX,m_daysEndDateVal,&m_daysStartDateVal.GetTickCount(),&COleDateTime::GeCurrentTime());
```

Whenever I change the FROM date it is not reflecting the possible dates in TO date picker.

How can i limit it to the starting date of the FROM date?

Comment: What is the type of m_daysStartDateVal and m_daysEndDateVal?

Comment: Why are you passing "&m_daysStartDateVal.GetTickCount()" when a "const COleDateTime*" is required?

Comment: Please adjust your question so it is more clear that you want the CDateTimeCtrl to change behaviour dynamically - not only the DDV_-calls. (At least that seems to be the case regarding your comment on Marius' answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dialog data validation does not work like that. You can only specified a (static) range, and the routine verifies that your value is within that pre-defined range. You can extended however this mechanism with your own validation routine.

The example function below takes two variables and a range, and makes sure

```
void AFXAPI DDV_MinMaxDates(
   CDataExchange* pDX,
   COleDateTime& fromValue, COleDateTime& toValue,
   const COleDateTime* refMinRange, const COleDateTime* refMaxRange)
{
  if(fromValue > toValue ||
     fromValue < refMinRange || fromValue > refMaxRange ||
     toValue < refMinRange || toValue > refMaxRange)
  {
     AfxMessageBox(_T("Incorrect interval!"));
     pDX->Fail();
  }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
DDV_MinMaxDates(pDX, m_daysStartDateVal, m_daysEndDateVal, &StartDate,&COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime());
```

Comment: I did the same to validate(message box). But i wanted to limit it dynamically at the date picker control (Calendar type) without using message box.

Comment: I do not see how DDV_MinMaxDates would help. The same checks can be done with DDV_MinMaxDateTime. The only difference is that you could provide a better error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `CDateTimeCtrl` controls to dynamically change the allowed ranges depending on the current input in both controls, then you can use `CDateTimeCtrl::SetRange`. To call `SetRange` every time one of the controls changed, you should handle the `DTN_DATETIMECHANGE` notification sent to the parent.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to MFC so I am struggling to get the work done.