# MFC initialize datetime picker control before custom validation gets executed

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog with two datetime controls whose format is set to time. One represents a start time and the other represents a end time.

One of the requirements is that the start time cannot be ahead of the end time and the end time cannot be before the start time.

So I am initializing the end time one hour ahead of whatever the current time is via the `SetTime()` function.

My problem is that I am initializing the two controls in the `OnInitDialog()` method, but `DoDataExchange()` is running before the `OnInitDialog()` function and thus the start time and end time are the exact same and it's causing my validation to fail and the dialog doesn't get created. The checking of the dates is being done in a custom validator which I adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032764/date-validation-in-mfc)

How can I get the datetime controls to be initialized first? Or am I perhaps not approaching this correctly or is there something I am missing?

In `OnInitDialog()`:

```
BOOL CNewManualEntryDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    m_dtStartTime.SetRange(&GetTodayTimeMin(), &GetTodayTimeMax());
    m_dtEndTime.SetRange(&GetTodayTimeMin(), &GetTodayTimeMax());

    m_dtEndTime.SetTime(&SetEndTimeOneHourAhead());

    return TRUE;
}
```

The functions above just return a `CTime` object.
For reference the validator looks like so:

```
void CNewManualEntryDlg::TimePickerValidation(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CTime startTime;
    CTime endTime;
    m_dtStartTime.GetTime(startTime);
    m_dtEndTime.GetTime(endTime);

    BOOL isStartTimeBehindEndTime = startTime > endTime;
    CString errorMsg;
    if (!isStartTimeBehindEndTime)
    {
        errorMsg += "Error - Start time cannot be ahead of end time\n";
    }
    if (!errorMsg.IsEmpty())
    {
        ::AfxMessageBox(errorMsg);
        pDX->Fail();
        return;
    }
```

}

And I am just calling it in `DoDataExchange()` as such:

```
void CNewManualEntryDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
   CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);

   DDX_Control(pDX, IDDT_STARTTIMEPICKER, m_dtStartTime);
   DDX_Control(pDX, IDDT_ENDTIMEPICKER, m_dtEndTime);

   TimePickerValidation(pDX);
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with moving SetRange and SetTime calls in DoDataExchange?

Comment: Won't putting `SetTime` in `DoDataExchange` override what the user entered via the dialog control?

Comment: pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate will let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing the validation always. Always means, you are performing the validation when you load the data into the dialog, and when you commit the data.

`DoDataExchange()` is called in both ways. You can determine the `pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate` to check if you are in the saving phase.

```
if (pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate)
   TimePickerValidation(pDX);
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that `DoDataExchange()` goes both ways (i.e. validating _on initialize_ and _on input_)